# Задача о распределении временных интервалов

Tags: алгоритм

Задан один временной интервал, в рамках которого будут распределятся процессы. Например 100 дней.

Есть `N` количество процессов, которые имеют разную продолжительность от 1 до  `M` дней.
В один и тот же момент времени не может выполнятся более чем `K` процессов.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы максимально рационально используя заданный интервал распределить все процессы.

Не могу понять как решать эту задачу. Может подскажете алгоритм, или вообще в какую сторону копать?

Update:
работник\станок у нас один, и одновременно может выполнятся не более K процессов. Последовательность и промежутки - не имеют значения. Под максимальной рациональностю подразумевается впихнуть в изначально заданный интервал все имеющиеся процессы, таким образом, что бы в один момент времени не выполнялось более K процессов. Если это невозможно - то решить задачу минимально выходя за рамки. На выходе мы должны получить последовательность выполнения процессов.

Comment: Что   данном сучае означает рациональность? Процессы могут/не могут выполняться одними и теми же работниками (одновременно можно/нельзя), оборудование не может/может использоваться одновременно, некоторые могут иметь определенную последовательность (один за другим и никак иначе)... да еще, возможно,с определенным промежутком (например, после возведения стен нельзя сразу же нагружать их крышей...)

Comment: @vikttur, больше никаких вводных нету.
То есть, работник\станок  у нас один,  и одновременно может выполнятся не более  `K` процессов. Последовательность и промежутки - не имеют значения.
Под максимальной рациональностю подразумевается впихнуть в изначально заданный интервал все имеющиеся процессы, таким образом, что бы в один момент времени не выполнялось более `K` процессов. 
Если это невозможно - то решить задачу минимально выходя за рамки.
На выходе мы должны получить последовательность выполнения процессов.

Comment: Заведите `K` пустых списков, отсортируйте процессы в порядке убывания продолжительности и начинайте добавлять. Самый продолжительный процесс в первый список, следующий во второй и так далее до `K`. Затем снова возвращайтесь к первому списку. Если суммарная продолжительность процессов в списке больше 100, попробуйте следующий список. Если процесс не помещается никуда, значит, процессы нельзя распределить таким образом. Добавляйте в самый короткий список, например, у него длина будет 105. Значит, 105 это минимум. Продолжайте распределять процессы до конца.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko, да, это неплохой вариант. Но он не достаточно полно решает задачу. То есть распределение  процессов в порядке продолжительности, уже не позволяет нам оптимизировать распределение процессов. Наверняка найдется такой вариант, при котором  чередование длинных и коротких процессов будет более оптимальным.

Comment: Видится родство данной задачи с задачей об укладке рюкзака. Только здесь имеется `K` рюкзаков одинаковой ёмкости... Возможно, задачу укладки можно попытаться обобщить для Вашего случая?

Comment: Пожалуй, первое что мне приходит в голову по поводу решения задачи, это следующий вариант: решаем задачу об укладке рюкзака (есть классические алгоритмы, которые можно нагуглить), затем из общего числа процессов исключаем процессы, которые вошли в "рюкзак". На оставшихся процессах снова решаем задачу укладки рюкзака... Всего сделать `K` итераций - возможно, это и будет оптимальным решением поставленной задачи (но не факт, хотя близость к оптимальному решению будет наверняка)

Comment: @RomanAndreev, в исходной задаче и в комментариях не определена *оптимальность* Определение *оптимальности* это не общие слова "должно быть хорошо", а измеримый в числах критерий.